# Être + de + infinitive?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, expressions, prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques

For example, I would like to inform my friend of a goal that I want to do today, and so I say, "My goal for today is to read about animals."

Using Google Translate and DeepL Translator yields the same result, « Mon objectif pour aujourd'hui est de lire sur les animaux ».

With that, I ask, why is *de* used here? At first I thought that it's part of *être* but when I checked WordReference, it didn't give me anything useful. Now I have a stinking feeling that the passive voice is involved here. And if so, are there any situations where you'd use *à* instead of *de* as well?

Comment: stinking feeling??

Comment: Using those programs are shortcuts. They only work if you already know the language in question. They do not show the proper form: Mon but aujourd'hui, **c'est de lire etc.**. L'important, c'est de [faire je-ne-sais quoi]. Remember Louis XIV who said; L'état, c'est moi. And not "est moi".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***De*** plays a role similar to what ***to*** does before an English infinitive.

> *In French the infinitive is often introduced by the word de (il a décidé de partir). French grammars usually define this de as a preposition whereas it can easily be analyzed as the same infinitive marker as the one used in Germanic languages (to, att, zu) and must therefore be considered as an element of the infinitive rather than a preposition. Incorporating the grammatical category of the infinitive marker in French grammar is not
> only a theoretical necessity; it would also greatly help learners to understand better several seemingly complicated rules regarding infinitive constructions and pronominalization.* Jean-Michel Kalmbach, *[Intégrer les marqueurs d’infinitif dans la grammaire française](https://gerflint.fr/Base/Paysscandinaves3/kalmbach.pdf)*, 2008.

You don't really omit it:

> <s>*Mon objectif pour aujourd'hui est lire sur les animaux.*</s>

If you really want to, you either insert a pause before *est*:

> *Mon objectif pour aujourd'hui est : lire sur les animaux.*

but then, dropping *est* would be also usually done:

> *Mon objectif pour aujourd'hui : lire sur les animaux.*

The sentence DeepL provided is not bad:

> *Mon objectif pour aujourd'hui est de lire sur les animaux.*

You might also say:

> *Mon objectif pour aujourd'hui, c'est de lire sur les animaux.*

With *c'est*, the *de* might be dropped:

> *Mon objectif pour aujourd'hui, c'est lire sur les animaux.*

e.g.:

> *Mon truc, ce ne sont ni les livres, ni les rencontres, c'est lire sur Internet, dit Biscotte. La toile, ça me fait kiffer !* Françoise DORN, *Graines de bonheur*, 2014

Comment: I see, I think it's starting to make sense now! In that case then, will it always be "de" that will be used to introduce an infinitive in this context, not "à"?

Comment: Yes, you can't use *à* here. It can't play the same role.

Comment: So with that, could I also say this? *De lire sur les animaux, c'est mon objectif pour aujourd'hui.* rather than, *À lire...*?

Comment: Technically, that seems possible but it really doesn't sound idiomatic.

Comment: That's interesting, are there any ways to know if something would sound idiomatic and such? On a another note, are there any notable instances where one would use this "*de* before any infinitive"? Do they happen before certain verbs, or phrases, tenses, etcetera?

Comment: *Are there any ways to know if something would sound idiomatic and such?* Yes, all you need to do is to be a native speaker ;-) By the way, in your question above, *À lire...* was plain wrong. The usual sentence would be: *Lire sur les animaux, c'est mon objectif pour aujourd'hui*. Even *lire sur les animaux* is not that idiomatic. It kind of gives the impression that something is written on some animals skin and you plan to read that ;-) I'd rather talk about *lire des livres sur les animaux*.

Comment: Oh so it's the sixth sense on language then ;D. And yeah, *À lire* does sound does sound a little bit weird now that I've given it much thought. Anyway, are there some reading materials about "the *de* that acts like *to* before an infinitive?" I'd like to explore more about it.

Comment: Sorting out idiomatic and non idiomatic constructions is very easy for a native speaker, whatever the language, and much more of an issue for someone learning it. Only experience (listening, reading) and practice can help here.